# Are there any Autopano Server alternative or automated panorama stitching/video panorama open source?

Tags: server-side, video-processing, panoramas, image-stitching

I haven't found any server side panorama making from stitching images or a video. I would like an open source alternative, but found any. I just don't want to go trough the hassle of developing all this on my own since but paid software usually are closed source and not very flexible.

I've seen some nifty panorama from video software in the iphone and thought it would be easy to find on *nix systems but with no luck.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only option I know is to use panostart (which is part of hugin) from whatever server language you are using.

See [here](http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell#Holding_it_all_together_with_panostart) for more information and other command line tools that do parts of the process more specifically.

panostart just works with images, so obviously if you wanted it to work with videos then you would have to process the videos with something like `ffmpeg -i z.mov -f image2 export2\%d.png` to generate images to pass to panostart.

The other alternative which requires more effort is to write something that uses libpano13 and libffmpeg directly.

Comment: I wanted an image stitching solution for server side, and panostart seems perfect accourding to its documentation on above link, but the problem is I cannot locate its binaries or tools to be installed!
any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/panotools/Panotools-Script/ci/default/tree/bin/panostart)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [VideoStitch](http://www.video-stitch.com), a command line is provided to automate the stitching.

Comment: It is a commercial product, the OP asked for an open source alternative.